# How to have Typescript target ES5 with React in Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, uglifyjs

We have a React web app written in Typescript that works fine and targets ES6 in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Now we want to minify it with Uglifyjs after compiling to deploy to production. That fails because Uglify supports only ES5 (even the #harmony branch, I tried that already).

So I need the webpack output to be ES5. But when I set `"target": "es5"` in our tsconfig file the webpack compilation fails saying: `Unexpected token (164:41) 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

How can we target ES5 in Typescript with React so that it works?

---

Attached a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have JSX there? It's hard to say anything concrete without seeing that line.

Comment: What's the unexpected token?

Comment: I attached the line with the error. But I don't think it's important. Everything compiles in ES6. So why would it fail in ES5? `target` is the version we are going **to**, not the version of the source code we are coming **from**.  No?

Comment: Some `ES6` features can not be compiled when targeting `ES5`, so you need to figure out what exactly the compiler is complaining about, and it's not clear from your screenshot.

Comment: I was not aware of that limitation. I thought Babel could do anything. Do you have a url listing unsupported features? Google is not helping

Comment: Ah, but maybe the solution is now that TS has compiled to ES6, Babel is not compiling to ES5 correctly. I'll review my webpack conf again to see.

Comment: When targeting `ES6` the compiler uses the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) instead of the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) and so some things (for example `Symbol`, `Iterator`, etc) won't be included when targeting `ES5`. I've never used Babel, but as I understand, it's a runtime tool and your problem is at compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, you can't.

Babel can transpile ES7 to ES6. But it [can't transpile ES6 to ES5](https://babeljs.io/), for that it uses a polyfill (.js library loaded in the browser).

Thus, because you cannot get ES5 from your source code, you cannot use Uglify.

You'll have to rely on gzipping alone ([which is a substantial size decrease](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-minification-and-gzipping/)).